# Accessing and Modifying xaml elements with Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, reflection

I have a model that has a number of attributes that may or may not be null, depending on if the data is available for those specific attributes on a remote server.

I'm building a simple windows phone application that gives more easily accessible versions of this information on a mobile phone. I found that in the case that the properties of the model above are not set, the value doesn't show up (shows a blank), but the label still shows up.

After considering a number of different alternatives for this (including massive amounts of if statements, ugh), I decided that if I set the name for specific attributes in the xaml to match the properties of the data model that I was looking at, I then in real time have the system analyze the properties of the data model, and elements of my xaml. If a property in my xaml matched the name of the property in my model, and the model was null, I could turn the visibility to collapsed. If the model was not null, make it visible. Thus I could have a clean, dynamic solution that would show only the data that is actually available.

Here's the code

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = data.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{

    FieldInfo view = this.GetType().GetField(property.Name);

    if (view != null)
    {
        if (property.GetValue(data, null) == null)
        {
            object aView = view.GetValue(this);
            aView.GetType().GetProperty("Visibility").SetValue(aView, "Collapsed", null);
        }
        else
        {
            object aView = view.GetValue(this);
            aView.GetType().GetProperty("Visibility").SetValue(aView, "Visible", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I hit a snag. I can't figure out how to access the xaml elements. I've tried to use

```
this.GetType().GetProperties()
this.GetType().GetFields()
this.GetType().GetMembers()
```

To find the elements that I'm looking for, but they don't show up in any of those. Is there something I'm missing.

Is there a better way to do this that is more beautiful?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  You should follow the MVVM pattern and bind the visibility to a property in your model that determines if your data us available.

Comment: @JeffMercado You don't have to follow the MVVM pattern! If this is a simple application a bit of code-behind will not do any harm.

Comment: If you have a suggestion for how to do that, I'm all ears! Ideally, the StackPanel that contains all of the elements related to this element would be visible/collapsed

Comment: @ColinE: Sure but then resorting to using reflection is certainly not the way to go.  Had he used MVVM, he'd get what he wants and more "beautiful."

Comment: Hey, if it's more beautiful, I'm all for it. I was just unable to figure out how to get this to work otherwise. Most of the posts I saw actually had code that was manually switching the visibility, which would be rather tedious to get for all the properties.

Comment: so I am using binding of the text value of the TextBlocks, but the thing I really need to be effecting is the visibility of the StackPanel that encapsulates everything associated with my data element. How would I bind to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom converter which is used in a Visibility binding expression for each element. This converter can check the property passed in, and if null, then return Collapsed as the value, otherwise Visible.

Similar to what you're doing, but all declarative, and much faster than using reflection.

Here is an example - http://digitalmoto.net/blog/2011/02/28/null-object-to-visibility-converter/

Comment: Sounds interesting, do you have any code you could suggest for this?

Comment: I've added an example. I'm trying to think of a way to automate it so that you wouldn't need to add a Visibility binding to every element. Are you always using this on the same type of element? i.e. are they all TextBlocks or Labels?

Comment: StackPanels would be a safe bet, usually, I have two textBlocks, one for the label, one for the value, wrapped in a horizontal stackPanel

Comment: Ok, so you want to check if the Text property of the 'value' TextBlock is null, and if so then hide the parent StackPanel. You could achieve this with a custom attached property. For example, one that is added to each StackPanel, and searches its children for the second TextBlock, and checks its Text property, and if null then sets its own Visibility to Collapsed. This attached property could then be applied to multiple StackPanels using Styles etc so that you don't need to manually add it to every individual StackPanel.

Comment: Another cleaner option is to model this in a view model when using MVVM. In this case you would have a collection of, for example, an Information type which contains Text and Value properties, and an IsVisible property (with a getter only that inspects the Value property). Then in your view you would have an ItemsControl bound to a collection of Information on your view model, and its ItemTemplate set to use a StackPanel, and two TextBlocks. Then it's a case of simple binding in the view, using the standard BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: I think your converter will work quite easily, I just have to get the namespace to work :)

Comment: I like the MVVM suggestion, do you have a link to an example you can send?

Comment: There is a bit to cover for MVVM, but you can start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/04/14/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.aspx. If you are going to use MVVM (and you probably should), then you should also look into using an MVVM framework - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913946/looking-for-the-wpf-mvvm-framework

Answer (score 5):

If you have named elements in your XAML as follows:

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock x:Name="txt" />
</Grid>
```

You can find them via the [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method:

```
TextBlock txt = this.FindName("txt") as TextBlock;
```

No reflection is required!

Comment: Founds great, except I think I'll still need reflection to get the names of all of the properties from the model to run this. Not saying that wouldn't work, just saying I'd still need reflection for the other side.

Comment: @JamieStarke OK - it does sound like MVVM might be a better route for your problem. By the way - as you are new to Stack Overflow, please remember to upvote any answers you find helpful. You don't have to mark them as answer if they are not a perfect fit, but upvotes are good :-)

Comment: @ExitMusic +1 on your comment for upvoting the OP so that he could upvote me ;-)